# Model to Controller / View Error Message

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm wanting to check if I can send a message from a Model to a Controller, I'll explain.

So I have a Model

```
public class Car()
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Make { get; set; }
}
```

So when a user adds a new Car, I could make it required by using Fluent API or the [Required] annotation.

But what if I wanted to make sure I had only certain characters in there, so I wouldn't want the percentage symbol in there (unless there are any cars out there?!).

So I thought I'll use a constructor:

```
public class Car()
{
   public Car(string _name)
   {
     if(this.Make.Contains("%"))
     {
       //Let the user know this isn't valid there is an error
     }
   }

   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Make { get; set; }
}
```

I usually place the error logic in the Controller. So I would have

```
public ActionResult AddCar(Car car)
{
  if(car.Make.Contains("%"))
  {
     //let user know this is not valid
  }
  if(ModelState.IsValid)
  {

  }
  ///
}
```

But then I thought, I'm never going to want to have a car Make with a % sign (I've picked on % sign, but actually there is a host of validation I would use, such as a list containing invalid characters), and every place in which I allowed for a user to add a car, I would duplicate the validation code, which just felt inefficient.

Maybe producing a the error checking in the controller is the correct way?

Again for clarity. The question, is there a way to pass a message from a Model to a Controller, which I can then pass to the User's view?

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

You should not use validation logic in your **controller**, we have `DataAnnotations` which allows us to validate model's properties value.

for your purpose you can use `RegularExpression` validator for this.

Refer to this [Link](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/15/asp-net-mvc-2-model-validation.aspx) for more details